# SQL Where clause variable needs to differ per row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, where-clause

Given the following data:

```
 ID, Name, Location, Date
 1,  Tom,  Boston, 8/12/2015
 1,  Tom,  Lowell, 7/12/2015
 1,  Tom,  Wakefield, 6/12/2015
 2,  Jake, Salem, 12/15/2018
 2,  Jack, Worcester, 5/12/2015
```

How would one write an SQL query which would return a table containing only the rows with largest dates, e.g.:

```
ID, Name, Location, Date
 1,  Tom,  Boston, 8/12/2015
 2,  Jake, Salem, 12/15/2018
```

Assuming that `ID` and `Name` are fixed keys. However, `location` may be variable, the `location` that should be returned would be the one associated with the maximum `date`.

My closest attempt is currently only returning for the MAX of all dates, not the record with the max date for the `ID` / `Name` pair. e.g.:

```
SELECT ID, NAME, Location, Data
 FROM Table A
 WHERE Date = (SELECT MAX(Date) FROM Table B WHERE A.ID = B.ID and A.Name = B.Name)
```

Only yields:

```
2,  Jake, Salem, 12/15/2018
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method 1:

```
SELECT A.* FROM [Table] A
JOIN (
    SELECT ID, Name, MAX([Date]) MaxDate
    FROM [Table]
    GROUP BY ID, Name
) B ON B.ID = A.ID AND B.Name = A.Name AND B.MaxDate = A.[Date]
```

Method 2:

```
SELECT ID, Name, [Location], [Date] FROM (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID, Name ORDER BY [Date] DESC) R
    FROM [Table]
) T
WHERE R = 1
```

Example:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (
    ID INT,
    Name VARCHAR(16),
    [Location] VARCHAR(16),
    [Date] DATE
)

INSERT @T VALUES
(1, 'Tom', 'Boston', '8/12/2015'),
(1, 'Tom', 'Lowell', '7/12/2015'),
(1, 'Tom', 'Wakefield', '6/12/2015'),
(2, 'Jake', 'Salem', '12/15/2018'),
(2, 'Jack', 'Worcester', '5/12/2015')

SELECT A.* FROM @T A
JOIN (
    SELECT ID, Name, MAX([Date]) MaxDate
    FROM @T
    GROUP BY ID, Name
) B ON B.ID = A.ID AND B.Name = A.Name AND B.MaxDate = A.[Date]

SELECT ID, Name, [Location], [Date] FROM (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID, Name ORDER BY [Date] DESC) R
    FROM @T
) T
WHERE R = 1
```

Comment: Thanks! Great example.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this works:

```
select ID, Name, Location, Date
from (
  select *, row_number() over (partition by ID order by Date desc) as RN
  from yourtable
) X
where RN = 1
```

The row number will add a sequential number for the rows, by dates descending, and the partition by means that it will restart the numbering every time the ID changes.

If you need to fetch multiple rows in case there's several rows with the same day, then use rank() instead of row_number()

Answer (score 1):

You can find the maximum date by grouping by `Id` field. Then `join` with the main table to find the final result.

```
SELECT X.*
FROM @T X INNER JOIN 
                    (
                        SELECT A.ID,MAX(A.Date) MaxDate
                        FROM @T A
                        GROUP BY A.ID
                                        ) Y 
ON X.ID = Y.Id AND x.Date = Y.MaxDate
ORDER BY Y.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try also this:

```
SELECT  a.ID, a.NAME, a.Location, a.Date
FROM  Table a
LEFT JOIN Table as b 
ON  b.ID = a.ID AND  b.Date > a.Date
WHERE  b.ID is NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Select ID,Name,Location,max(Date) as Date 
FROM table_name 
group by ID
```

Hope this works.

Comment: The statement is malformed as `Name` and `Location` aren't in the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 0):

You're close. Try adding `GROUP BY` into your subquery and change `=` to `IN`.

```
SELECT ID, NAME, Location, [Date]
FROM Table A
WHERE Date in ( 
                SELECT MAX(Date) 
                FROM Table B 
                WHERE A.ID = B.ID and A.Name = B.Name 
                GROUP BY ID, Name    )
```

Another better way is to create `view` from your subquery  and `join` table on view.